# Using AWS javascript sdk getting No Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS javascript browser version to upload a file into AWS S3 server. And I am getting the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/cortex.myauscript.upload/uploadcontent-upload-development/TestFileName.txt.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 403.

I have searched about this error but I can confirm that the CORS setting on that bucket is setted correctly. So I am a bit confused here.

Below is my code:

```
    var bucketName = 'cortex.myauscript.upload';
    AWS.config.region = 'ap-southeast-2';
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId : 'test',
        secretAccessKey : 'test'
    });

    var bucket = new AWS.S3({
        params: {
            Bucket: bucketName
        }
    });

    var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file-chooser');
    var button = document.getElementById('upload-button');
    var results = document.getElementById('results');

    $("#upload-button").click(function() {
        var file = fileChooser.files[0];
        if(file) {
            var params = {
                Key: 'uploadcontent-upload-development/TestFileName.txt',
                ContentType: file.type,
                Body: file
            };
            bucket.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt){
                console.log("Uploaded :: " + parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total)+'%');
            }).send(function(err, data) {
                alert("File uploaded successfully.");
            });
        }
    });
```

I am also a little bit wondering, will the wrong key/security key generate the same error. I am not 100% sure about that.

Thanks.

Comment: "I can confirm that the CORS setting on that bucket is setted correctly" — it isn't. If it was, you wouldn't get that error.

Comment: @Quentin I have checked many times today on that. And that bucket is an existing one. Other code runs pretty smoothly on it. Is there any chance it is caused by any other things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're running your app from `file://` instead of `http://` which produces a `null` origin that cannot be authorized.